# How to determine week number within calendar quarter period VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

Having some trouble locating a function to determine the week number of a quarter period in a standard date based (i.e. Day 1 = 2017-01-01) calendar table.

My table has the following information stored :

**Quarter Number**, **Beginning Date**, **End Date**, **Number of Days**;

As an example, for the first quarter of calendar year, the result for Week 1 would be 1, Week 14 would be 1, going through each quarter until the final week of quarter 4.

Any ideas please help?

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: the question is: "who is willing to code such a boring function for me?" [sarcasm]

Comment: @deblocker that was my impression as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in function for this. If I understand what you're asking, this is a trivial function to write. You don't include any code so I'm just giving you the most basic example. You want to do something similar to this.

```
Public Function GetWeekInQuarter(ByVal WeekNumber As Integer) As Integer
    Const intWeeksInQuarter = 13
    Dim intResult As Integer

    intResult = WeekNumber Mod intWeeksInQuarter
    'if intResult <> intWeeksInQuarter = 0 then this is the 13th week
    GetWeekInQuarter = IIf(intResult <> intWeeksInQuarter, intResult, intWeeksInQuarter)

End Function
```